# Dim, almost transparent activity with actionbarsherlock

Tags: android

I want my activity to be dimmed, almost transparent. Like the spotify app, the beneath example is from the iPhone application, but the behaviour is almost the same

[image]

Lets pretend that this is an android application, the view in front is an activity, and the view behind is also an activity. Which property do I need to set in my `res/styles.xml` in order to get this design? I've googled but I can only find java examples like this one:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams windowManager = getWindow().getAttributes();
    windowManager.dimAmount = 0.75f;
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution:

Create your own Theme in the `res/styles.xml`

```
 <style name="Theme.Opacity" parent="Sherlock.__Theme.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
     <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
     <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
 </style>
```